# why can i embed wordpress admin into an iframe?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

Hello to the whole community, as my question indicates, I would like to be able to insert an iframe in my portfolio (which is not a wordpress) and this iframe, I would like it to contain the page "www.mysite.com/wp-admin" but this does not work.

With the page "www.mysite.com", it works but not with the admin.

Several posts on this subject say that it is enough to add this:

```
Remove_action ('login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0);
Remove_action ('admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0);
```

But it does not work either.

Somebody would have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I first tried it on the same domain name and it worked, so I tested it with different domains and apparently it is not possible because of the following:

```
 "Refused to display 'www.mysite.com/wp-login.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
```

One solution could be editting your .htacces file:

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
    Header always unset X-Frame-Options
</IfModule>`

However I would recommend finding a total different solution to your problem, why you want to load your wp-admin in an iframe on another website in the first place?

Comment: It's because i've got a lot of wordpress sites and i want to make a multiplex page of iframes with wordpress login pages to manage all wordpress into a single page. I read that i could add the domain of the multiplex page to a white list for X-Frame-Options but i don't find how to do it. Else, i will use your solution. It's maybe not good but admin is password protetced

Comment: I would really recommend just putting links on this website so the login screen opens in a new window. I see you could also add the following to your configuration -> X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM yoursite.com. Is that what you tried?

Comment: yes i think that it's what i look for, i will try it.

the apache header mod is enabled but the "Header unset X-Frame-Options" does not work